# Downloading Borland BCC

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, borland-c++

I hear widely that the Borland C++ 5.5 compiler is freely available. Searching for a download link generally only leads me to an embarcadero.com page, which I'm damned if I can figure out...

Any know a simple, straightforward way to download BCC 5.5? (for windows)

(Yes, BCC is super old and crusty. But it's part of a legacy tool chain for Flagship, which I need to use. I think it's the path of least resistance to use BCC in this case.)

**EDIT : Short answer is [download straight from here](http://altd.embarcadero.com/download/bcppbuilder/freecommandLinetools.exe).**

Comment: Did this not work? http://forms.embarcadero.com/forms/BCC32CompilerDownload

Comment: it just worked for me, sent an email with link to the download.

Comment: Cheers, guys - as it turns out, I wasn't supplying my email address, so I didn't get a download link sent to me.

Comment: Holy jesus. Check out those amazing Windows95-era installer graphics.

Comment: Single compiler without ide is not worth much. Try to search for "bds 2006 Turbo C++" + registration text file on torrents. its free for 100 years with the only restriction that only 1 language can be installed on 1 computer. sadly embarcadero close the download and registration site so torrents are the only option. There should be still out there. I am using it for years now ... has some issues as all builders but if you know what to avoid then its a super IDE (i like it the most of all IDEs i am working with).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to [Borland C++ Compiler version 5.5 Free Download Is Here !!!](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/20633)
2. Click on [is now available for free download](http://forms.embarcadero.com/forms/BCC32CompilerDownload) on our Web site.
3. Fill the form.
4. Your download link will be sent by email.

Alternatively, Google Search shows [this form](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Free.aspx?id=24778) that presumably will have the same effect.

Enjoy what was once one of the greatest IDEs and compilers around.

Comment: Oh man. Thanks for that, will check out tonight. I was passive-aggressively refusing to supply my true email address, so of course I get no link ... :P

Comment: In that case, creating a temporary or disposable email address is an option.